# TortoiseSVN - How to update to last version on server after having reverted to a previous version?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN. I reverted to a previous version to run the program (data processor) and compare its output with the current version, I am doing this to find out if a bug was introduced. My problem is that I can't Update to the last revision on the server. I tried:

- From the log, clicking on "Update to this revision"(last one).
- Doing a regular update of my "reverted" code.
- Committing the "reverted code" with a small change.

None of the previous attempts has helped me to pull the code from the last committed revision. Does anyone know how can I pull that last revision?

Comment: Why the down vote? How is that supposed to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the project directory and do `TortoiseSVN - Update to revision`

You should then have an dialog like this. Make sure `HEAD` is selected.
[image]

An alternative is to do TortoiseSVN - Switch.

Make sure you have HEAD selected and select trunk (or whatever branch you are currently on). This should also force an update.

[image: TortoiseSVN - Switch]